# circle ci having error i don't know what's the error

Tags: javascript, node.js, config, circleci

i was trying to add circle ci in my branch because i have many branches and i added circleci and config file lite this  :

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@5.0.2
  heroku: circleci/heroku@1.2.6

jobs:
  build_and_test:
    executor: node/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - node/install-packages:
          pkg-manager: npm
      - run:
          command: npm run test
          name: Run tests
      - run:
          command: npm run build
          name: Build app
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ~/project
          paths:
            - .

  deploy: # this can be any name you choose
    executor: heroku/default
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/project
      - heroku/deploy-via-git:
          force: true # force push when pushing to the heroku remote, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

workflows:
  test_my_app:
    jobs:
      - build_and_test
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build_and_test # only deploy if the build_and_test job has completed
          filters:
            branches:
            only: main
              # only: main # only deploy when on main
```

this was the error from circle ci:

```
ERROR IN CONFIG FILE:
[#/workflows/test_my_app] only 1 subschema matches out of 2
1. [#/workflows/test_my_app/jobs/1] 0 subschemas matched instead of one
|   1. [#/workflows/test_my_app/jobs/1] expected type: String, found: Mapping
|   |   SCHEMA:`
```

this was the error from circle ci:

```
ERROR IN CONFIG FILE:
[#/workflows/test_my_app] only 1 subschema matches out of 2
1. [#/workflows/test_my_app/jobs/1] 0 subschemas matched instead of one
|   1. [#/workflows/test_my_app/jobs/1] expected type: String, found: Mapping
|   |   SCHEMA:**strong text**`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the line `only: main` (the one just below `branches`). See examples of the correct formatting [here](https://circleci.com/docs/workflows/#executing-workflows-for-a-git-tag).